# iis7 + php fopen problems

Tags: php, windows, iis-7

I can't write Engilsh well...

My setup is Windows 2008 + iis7 + php5

I have an `fopen` problem.

Instead of being downloaded, the file displays as text in the webpage.

Examples:

PK!XVƏ`�[Content_Types].xml ��(�̔MN�0��H�!�%n��J�?K���ؓƪc[���g��J����D�5���f�|��M����قM� K�J��]�u��޲��Jg�`@��*^䫃L��b����(+�f΃��҅ZD� k��܈5��drå�lLc���� ZA�!>��|���Hj�=�����+l� &�7Z�H��Ϊo��+K-A9���+kŮ��!ƃm�>�PX��d����J�51y��z���� 3�ʶ}����av�L�]ؼ9��k* ���s�-Mo�GN�� T�IB�pb��M ��ގy�����u5N�C zr\���o�/x�vB���8ޝ��gx�*���PK!�U0#�L �_rels/.rels ��(����N�0 ��H�C���nH���LH�!T�$����$@����Jc�����?[���iTb/Nú(A�3b....

What's the problem?

sorry;;;

it's codes

```
    Header("Content-type: file/unknown");
    Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$oriname");
    Header("Content-Description: PHP3 Generated Data");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($files));
    header("Cache-control: must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");   

$fp=fopen("$files","rb"); 
    while(!feof($fp)){ 
    echo fread($fp,100*1024); 
    flush();
    } 
fclose($fp);
```

$files is filepath and filename.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. What code have you used?

Comment: Please include your code that calls `fopen`.

Comment: sorry;; slip my mind